# Distribute application with user defined heap size

Tags: java, parameters, jvm, executable, user-input

We are distributing a Java application exe file using install4j, and setting the JVM parameters (e.g. `vmParameters="-Xmx512m ..."`).
Problem is, that some users needs different MaxHeapSize, and we want to allow user-defined JVM parameterization (say, by launching the `.exe` from cmd with params). How can we achieve this?

### EDIT

I know about `launch4j` and other executable wrappers, but couldn't find any of which that works with `.exe` file (only for `.jar`s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, a colleague found the answer - create a `.vmoptions` file next to the `.exe` and add the options you want to pass to the JVM (in this case `-Xmx1024mb`).